# making complex queries using python and facebook marketing api (targeting)

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

i am trying to make complex queries in order to know things like "the is the size of population (audience size) of people who are interested in football and also live in new york".
i have access token, and yet i can't make complex conditions, only 1 condition at a time. another problem is that i take the curl code and i conver it to python code using https://curl.trillworks.com/
so far i did this code:

```
import requests
data2 = [('type', 'adinterest'),('q','football'), 
('access_token','my_access_token'),('limit','1000')]
response = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/search',params=data2)
r=response.json()
```

how can i make it into more complicated query like "is interested in football, in age between 18 and 30 and also live in new york" ?
i looked at facebook explanations like:
    https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search
    https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api/targeting

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs

and yet i fail.

Comment: What you have above is the search endpoint only, that is not the place where you combine this stuff in the first place. You need to perform individual searches to get the targeting ids for football, living in NY, and age separately - and then you use those ids afterwards when creating your ad set, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs#flexible

Comment: in order to get the audiance number, do i need a facebook ad account id?
or campaign id?
can you please make an example code?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t even understand what exactly you want to know now. Are you trying to create an actual ad set, or just to get audience sizes upfront for whatever purpose, or …?

Comment: i don't want to make ads or advertise in any way. all i want is to get audience sizes of groups depending on many conditions (like interests, age, location)

Comment: In that case, I don’t see how that data would be any of your business to begin with, sorry. This is tied directly to the purpose of advertising, and not to satisfy whatever else curiosities you might have.

Comment: it is not about a personal curiousity, i am doing a scientific research. i try to predict illness using facebook. will you please help me?

Comment: Sorry, but that’s not the purpose of this API. May your motives be pure as can be, that doesn’t change that using this API is tied to very specific terms. If anything, I would suggest that you try and contact Facebook somehow, to see if they would be willing to cooperate on this somehow.

Comment: facebook api is used constantcly for research purposes. and by the way, the fact that i am using it for research right now does not mean that it will stay like it. for example: the research can result in a patent which we predict deseases, and later on hospitals and health institutions can advertise for flu vaccine.
the research is just part one.